# How to overlap something over a Google Map div?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

[UI Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIsII.png)

I have this UI design above. It has a Google Map on it, I know how to do those. What I'm worried about is that overlay with all the locations on it, I'd like to overlap it over the Google Map div. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use css position to do this. eg - https://codepen.io/akhilashokan/pen/OJvdzdd